# Weird echo output in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, dig

I'm struggling with a really simple Cygwin script, but I can't get my head around it. Hope someone can give me a hand.

Here you are the script:

```
h=www.ibm.com
for ip in $(dig $h +short); do echo "XX ${ip} XX"; done
```

Expected output (tested with Debian Buster Linux and bash 5.0.3(1)-release:

```
XX www.ibm.com.cs186.net. XX
XX outer-global-dual.ibmcom-tls12.edgekey.net. XX
XX e7817.dscx.akamaiedge.net. XX
XX 37.26.112.89 XX
```

Running the same script in Cygwin with bash 4.4.12(3)-release, the output is quite different:

```
 XXwww.ibm.com.cs186.net.
 XXouter-global-dual.ibmcom-tls12.edgekey.net.
 XXe7817.dscx.akamaiedge.net.
 XX37.26.112.89
```

I can't believe what's happening. It must be something obvious, but I can't see it. Why is the bash of Cygwin trimming the last "XX" and the leading space?

Regards,

Comment: The output from `dig` seems to have trailing carriage-returns that move the cursor back to the start of the line.

Comment: You were absolutely right. Thank you. Getting rid of the trailing carriage returns did the trick: `for ip in $(dig $h +short); do i=$(echo $ip|sed 's/\r$//'); echo "XX \"$i\" XX"; done`

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Cygwin using `DiG 9.11.9` (run `dig -v` to get your version). For me it works correctly as shown in your Debian Buster results. What _exactly_ did you type at the Cygwin prompt? I'll do exactly the same here and see what I get

Comment: Are you using `dig` as provided by Cygwin, or is it a separate executable? A Windows-native version of `dig` could well output lines with CR/LF, whereas the Cygwin version writes lines terminated with just LF. (Check with `type dig` and post the result into your question.)

Comment: Hi. I do appreciate your comments. Indeed, I was using the standalone dig utility included in Bind9 for Windows. I searched for dig in the Cygwin setup but didn't find it. Then, I realized it was in bind-utils.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dig` utility appears to output lines ending with a carriage-return character on Cygwin (I have no way of testing this).  When this character is outputted, it moves the cursor back to the start of the line, which gives rise to the oddly formatted output.

To fix this, strip the trailing carriage-return characters from the output of `dig`:

```bash
query=www.ibm.com

dig "$query" +short | sed 's/[[:space:]]*$//' |
while IFS= read -r response; do
    printf 'XX %s XX\n' "$response"
done
```

This uses `sed` to remove anything matching `[[:space:]]*$`  from the output of `dig`.  The pattern matches zero or more space-like characters, of which carriage-return is one, at the end of the line.

I've chosen to use a `while` loop instead of your `for` loop.  Conceptionally, a `while` loop is for reading lines from a stream of data of indeterminate length while the data is arriving.  A `for` loop, on the other hand, always iterates over a *static* set of strings. This means that the `for` loop can't start until the shell has read all output from `dig` and split it up into words (and applied filename globbing to each of those words). Generally, using `for` to read the lines of output from a program is problematic due to potential quoting issues, but also inelegant and possibly memory intensive (as all output has to be stored by the shell).

Comment: "_The dig utility appears to output lines ending with a carriage-return character on Cygwin_" no, it doesn't do this in version `DiG 9.11.9`. (I'm convinced it's a CR/LF file line-endings issue but without more data I can't prove it.)

Comment: @roaima Well, if it's the script that is a DOS text file, then they are not showing the code that they run.

Comment: Agreed. Let's wait and see...

Comment: The problem was I was using dig from Bind9 for windows package. It wasn't the dig utility included in bind-utils package. Anyway, getting rid of the trailing carriage return characters, did the trick.

Comment: By the way, thanks for the advice about the "while" and "for" loops. Most informative.